# Problem w/Micro B USB 2.0 5pin female

Tags: usb-device

I busted my STFjoy boombox by dropping the box with the charger port plugged in. I opened the box and found the USB charger port needed to be resoldered. I bought the soldering equipment and found I had to ply out the entire usb female port. During soldering I left the soldering tip on the circuit too long and I'm wondering if I should buy a new charger port off amazon or throw the entire fix away. My concern lies with the way I burned the PCB.

[image: Fix1]

[image: Fix2]

[image: Fix3]!

Edit: I might have tried resoldering the usb port too many times. The connectors dont look the same anymore and the PCB looks damaged. Thoughts? Repairable?

[image: FixAfter1]
[image]

Comment: What is the residue on the board? Some kind of flux that you used? When you say you dropped it, did you drop it in water? Is this just a charging port?

Comment: I didn't drop it in water, the device was charging and it fell several times wriggling the port solder. Yes, the residue on the circuit is flux paste.

Comment: It looks like you ripped off the ground pad in the middle, but it might not matter depending on the design. You also have a couple pins that are jumpered together. I'd try to clean up the contacts using some solder wick and see how damaged it really is. It's difficult to see what the land's are looking like, but you'll definitely need a new USB port.

Comment: Does the USB port have any function besides charging, at least that you actually need?   See if you can figure out where the signals go, for example the fat trace just inside the jack might be VBus and ground is easy to find.  Sometimes its easiest to fix things like this by cutting the end off an old cable (maybe one where the micro end has gone bad) and soldering that to the board.   Just be sure to check the cable with a meter as sometimes the colors are not standard(!).   Alas the two little traces to vias at the side make it look like it might need the D+/D- signal lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have not damaged the PCB, just melted the connector from what I can tell.

Replace the connector, clean all the pads up with solder braid gently, you want no solder left on them to make fitting the new one as easy as possible, I would probably even remove that LED when you fit the new one,

When you do get the new connector, ignore the center pad, if all you have is an iron, the edge pads will have to do,

Start by aligning the 5 pins, and then tack one of the 4 edge pads to hold it in place, once your happy, tack an opposite corner,

With all this done, heat from the edge or the top of the usb pins, go slowly 1 at a time, only adding small amounts of solder for each,

Once that looks good, secure the 4 corner pads with a decent amount of solder and you should be back in business.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried as you've suggested and I might have really burnt the PCB. The connectors no longer look 'good'. I've uploaded some pictures that show how it now looks.